# AWS Cognito oAuth login and Passwordless login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to setup AWS Cognito User Pool with for Passwordless login following this [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/). However, one of the conditions is to "Only allow custom authentication". But I need my application to allow users to use couple of other providers (oAuth and SAML) and also passwordless login.

How can I make sure user cannot somehow login with the random password that is generated during the above process? or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I will quote the same source but with with more context

> [The user pool] has an app client that’s configured to “Only allow
> custom authentication”. This is because when a user signs up, Amazon
> Cognito requires a password. We’ll supply a random string for this. We
> don’t want users to be able to actually log in with this password
> later.

Your user pool can have multiple app clients. So you will have one app client for OAuth and SAML etc and a different one for passwordless. Both app clients will give you tokens to the same user pool.

Its also worth questioning their premise to enforce custom authentication only. Their rationale is that they create a random password for the user, which is never shared with them, that could in theory be used to login with. I guess you could consider this a security risk, but unless you're running a bank or something it doesn't sound vary concerning to me. If you used a long crypt-secure generator, I really can't see anyone guessing you're users 'secret' passwords. Cognito has brute force protection built in.